# subsonic 3.0 active record update

Tags: subsonic3

I am able to retrieve database values and insert database values, but I can't figure out what the Update() syntax should be with a where statement.

Environment -> ASP.Net, C#

```
Settings.ttinclude

    const string Namespace = "subsonic_db.Data";
    const string ConnectionStringName = "subsonic_dbConnectionString";

    //This is the name of your database and is used in naming
    //the repository. By default we set it to the connection string name
    const string DatabaseName = "subsonic_db";
```

Retreive example

```
var product = equipment.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == 1);
```

Insert Example

```
   equipment my_equipment = new equipment();

    try
    {
        // insert
        my_equipment.parent_id = 0;
        my_equipment.primary_id = 0;
        my_equipment.product_code = product_code.Text;
        my_equipment.product_description = product_description.Text;
        my_equipment.product_type_id = Convert.ToInt32(product_type_id.SelectedItem.Value);
        my_equipment.created_date = DateTime.Now;
        my_equipment.serial_number = serial_number.Text;

        my_equipment.Save();

    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lblError.Text = err.Message;
    }
```

Edit: Think that I was just too tired last night, it is pretty easy to update. Just use the retrieve function and use the Update() on that.

```
    var equip = Equipment.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == 1);

    lblGeneral.Text = equip.product_description;

    equip.product_description = "Test";
    equip.Update();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. View answer above.